# Image isn't shown in pdf with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, puppeteer, pdfmake

I'm generating a pdf from an html sample with puppeteer and handlebars. Everything works good except an image is shown in the browser (headless mode) but when pdf is generated the image disappear. I don't know why this happens.

It's weird because I'm not getting any error, the image (logo) just doesn't appear, just does in the browser view.

I'm calling the image through a external link in the img label in sample.html.

I leave you my code

file.json

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const hbs = require("handlebars");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

const data = {
    date: sale.transaction.createdAt,
    time: sale.transaction.createdAt,
    raffleDate: sale.transaction.createdAt,
    description:
      "Zapatos NikeZapatos NikeZapatos NikeZapatos NikeZapatos NikeZapatos NikeZapatos NikeZapatos NikeZapatos Nike",
    "name-customer": sale.transaction.customer.firstName,
    "lastname-customer": sale.transaction.customer.lastName,
    "raffle-code": raffleId,
    tickets: ticks,
    quantity: tickets.length,
    total: sale.transaction.amount,
  };
  
  const compile = async (templateName, data) => {
    const filePath = path.join(
      process.cwd(),
      `./controllers/sample-email/${templateName}.html`
    );
    const html = await fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf-8");

    return hbs.compile(html)(data);
  };
       
  (async () => {
    try {          
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
      });
   
      const page = await browser.newPage();
   
      const content = await compile("sample", data);
     
      await page.setContent(content, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
      
      await page.addStyleTag({
        path: "./controllers/sample-email/sample.css",
      });
     
      await page.emulateMediaType("screen");        
     
      await page.pdf({
        path: "./controllers/sample-email/sample.pdf",
        format: "A4",
        printBackground: true,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  })();
```

sample.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/controllers/sample-email/sample.css" />
   <title>Invoice</title>
   </head>
   <body>

    <header>
    <section class="logo">
     <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/baltasar-montero-vidaurreta-175/image/upload/v1687201343/algira/thumbnails/ALGIRA.webp"
      alt="algira"
    />
   </section>
   </header>
   </body>
   </html>
```